# Как проверить отсортирован ли массив из целых чисел по возрастанию?

Tags: c

Вот мой код. С положительными числами работает, но если внести в массив отрицательные или 0, то даже если массив отсортирован в порядке возрастания - пишет, что не отсортирован.

```
#include
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main()
{
int i, j, size, cum ;
printf("Vvedite kol-vo elementov massiva: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
int array[size];
printf("Vvedite elementi massiva: \n");
for (int i = 1; i<=size; i++) {
scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
for (int i = 1; i<=size; i++) {
j = i-1;
if (array[i] > array[j])
cum = TRUE;
else {
cum = FALSE;
break;
}
}
if (cum == FALSE){
printf("Массив не отсортироaан\n");
}
else {
printf("Массив отсортирован\n");
}
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int main()
{
    int i, j, size, cum ;
    printf("Vvedite kol-vo elementov massiva: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int array[size];
    printf("Vvedite elementi massiva: \n");
    for (int i = 1; i<=size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i<=size; i++) {
        j = i+1;
        if (array[j] > array[i])
            cum = TRUE;
        else {
            cum = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (cum == FALSE){
        printf("Массив не отсортироaан\n");
    }
    else {
         printf("Массив отсортирован\n");
    }
    if (0>-1){
        printf("0 > -1\n");
    }
    if (0<1){
        printf("0 < 1\n");
    }
    if((0>-1)&&(-1>-2)&&(1>0)&&(1>-1)&&(-1<-2)){
    printf("true");
    }
}
```

Comment: `i<=size;` при i равным size вы выходите  за последний элемент массива. А при вводе данных ничего не пишете в первый элемент (у него индекс равен 0)

Comment: элементы могут быть и равны, у Вас это не учитывается